# Is there any danger in disabling windows firewall on a azure worker role?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012, azure, windows-firewall

I'm trying to troubleshoot a bug on our Azure worker role where we occasionally get the error "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine". This error occurs when we are connecting to outside resources like google auth servers.

A few people have recommended disabling the firewall\antivirus on the server.  I'm just wondering what kind of security risk we would take by doing this.  The server doesn't have iis installed but would it be vulnerable to hacking without the firewall?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is generally a bad idea to disable the firewall on any server. If it is am intermittent error, it seems unlikely that it is a firewall issue. A firewall would have blocked traffic every single time.